# android studio error application crushing when i put this code

Tags: java

```
private void loadUserDetails() {
    binding.textName.setText(preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
    byte[] bytes=Base64.decode(preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE),Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0, bytes.length);
    binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

my app is crushining wen i put the base64 prompt anyone to help

i tried removing

```
    private void loadUserDetails() {
  
    byte[] bytes=Base64.decode(preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE),Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0, bytes.length);
    binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```